# Ubuntu 18.04 Apache 2.4.29 After changing mpm_prefork to mpm_event, apache just serves php source code

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm

I followed this but got crazy results:
[switch apache from prefork to event in Ubuntu 16, get php 7 working](https://serverfault.com/questions/904065/switch-apache-from-prefork-to-event-in-ubuntu-16-get-php-7-working)

My goal is to also enable http2, which is not compatible with mod_prefork.
What happens is apache starts up but only serves the source of all PHP pages. I know I'm using mpm_event because a2query -M tells me so, also third party sites which test for http2 return success, but only for the php source! Swapping everything back with a2enmod php7.2 makes everything work again, but back with the old mpm_prefork and no http2.

I must be close because apache runs. The only things in the apache error log are several lines like

```
[Thu Feb 28 17:06:08.489893 2019] [:error] [pid 15062:tid 140075829955520] avahi_entry_group_add_service_strlst("admin on master") failed: Local name collision
```

I think avahi is related to http2. Non-php sites work OK. Anyone spot how to get php going again under this config please?

Comment: How have you configured Apache to call php-fpm?

Comment: I used a2enconf php7.2-fpm
I also made the entry in 000-default.conf as shown here https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-run-apache2-with-php7-2-fpm-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04/